# HP ProCurve Switch 4100 series - Checking PSU status & S/N from the CLI

Tags: switch, hp-procurve, power

Do you know if there is any CLI command available on the very old HPE Procurve 4108gl/J4865A switches where you can see how many PSUs are installed in the chassis, what's their current status and serial number?

(Something like what can be achieved on Cisco with 'show environment power' and 'show inventory' commands).

If there is no direct command for this available, then maybe you know if it could be extracted through SNMP MiBs?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Quite an ancient piece you've got there...

Have you tried

```
show system
show system power
show system chassis
```

?

else try

```
show system [tab]
show [tab]
```

Regarding SNMP, you should download the current MIBs from HPE but it's quite possible that that old chassis has another structure.

[late edit]
On the 4200 series, there seem to be some PSU details during bootup - connect a serial terminal to the console port, set to 9600/8/N/1 and reboot the switch. Perhaps something turns up that points in the right direction.

Comment: I have tried all of those, sadly nothing. The command for other swappable modules works but sadly only shows S/Ns of tranceivers and such...

Comment: You might have to look at the back of the unit..... :-/

Comment: Sadly, no physical access to the device - my company is only remotely administering these old boxes for another company.

Comment: Well, good luck on that feat. Pull configs and replace. ;-)

Comment: The odd thing is that our syslog is discovering 2 PSUs, the switch generates a lot of alerts for the 2nd one "W 03/17/21 09:53:11 chassis: Power Supply failure:  Supply: 2, Failures: 9902" but there isn't even any command to check it from the CLI and the customer claims there has always been just 1 PSU installed in the chassis... :)

Comment: Syslog events should also show up in the system log (`show log`) unless some special `debug` is in place.

Comment: Oh but they do show up, that's the odd part about it. There has never been any 2nd PSU installed in this chassis and the device never complained about it, yet suddenly the logbuffer visible under "show log" has been flooded by messages such as the one I quoted above. Our "inventory server" which collects information about hw modules from devices by SNMP, is also receiving info from the switch that supposedly there are 2 PSUs installed.

Comment: "suddenly"? Without config/firmware changes?

Comment: Exactly. No software updates, no configuration changes done, not even a power cycle (though a reboot was attempted AFTER the alert appeared and the monitoring system generated a ticket for us - alas it did not help though)

Comment: Weird. I'd try a full power cycle though.

Comment: I believe that it has actually been tried already, I personally had a day off that day though. At any rate, we even contacted HP TAC about it, cos the issue is actually visible not just in the logbuffer but also on the front LED display panel and thus visible to the customer's onsite staff. No other issues have been found with the switch, the customer is pleased with the overall network performance, they're only worried about that visible LED alert. 

HP TAC said that a chassis with as many modules as ours should have 2 PSUs but I'm not sure how reliable their words are.

Comment: Most of the time I feel like all those TACs (CTAC, JTAC or HPTAC) aren't able to isolate the root cause and simply suggest the usual steps: reboot/firmware upgrade/device replacement. 

On the other hand, my teammates think that maybe the customer connected some new, more power-consuming devices and that's why the switch started generating these alerts (ie. W 03/17/21 09:53:11 chassis: Power Supply failure: Supply: 2, Failures: 9902") but I'm not convinced by this assumption. The customer isn't complaining about the performance of the switch and even when the primary PSU would be overloaded

Comment: - even then the switch should rather be generating alerts for that primary PSU, not for the non-existent redundant (secondary) PSU...

Comment: Totally agree. I'd keep nagging HPE so that they escalate the issue to a specialist.